# Power Query ; Determine in which row and column a certain string appears in a table

Tags: powerbi, powerquery

Let's say I have this table below:

| Column 1 | Column 2 | Column 3 | Column 4 | Column 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  | Hello |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |

Could you help me figuring out the Power Query steps to determine the row (bonus question: what column) where "Hello" appears? IN my example in would be in row 2 (and column 4), but the number of rows can vary and the location of the "Hello" too.

Thanks

I haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Do any of these answers solve your issue? If so, please toggle checkmark to mark question as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought it would be fun to try to make this from scratch with some m-code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    Lst = List.Transform(Table.ToList(Source), (x)=> let y=List.PositionOf(Text.Split(x,","), "Hello")+1 in if y>0 then y else null),
    Col = List.RemoveNulls(Lst){0},
    Row = List.PositionOf(Lst, Col)+1
in
    Row
    //Col
```

Depending on what you are after you can change 'Row' to 'Col' under 'in'. Also, note that you can change the delimiter for `Table.ToList()` with a 2nd parameter `Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter("|")` if need be. Make sure to change the delimiter in `Text.Split()` to the same.

Answer (score 1):

Add column ... index column

Right click the index column and unpivot other columns

Filter the remaining column to see if contains your text using the arrow atop the column

What's left is the row number and the column name it appeared in